# python requests in AWS EC2 instance. HTTPConnectionPool Error

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, python-requests

I'm planning to use python requests in AWS EC2 instance.

Here is code that is working well in my local dev case:

```
url = http://m.dcinside.com/board/twice/8072990?recommend=1&page=14
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'
}
try:
    req = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, headers=headers)
except Exception as e:
    print('requests error: ' + str(e) + ' at: ' + url)
    return
```

But in AWS EC2 instance it showed me this:

```
requests error: HTTPConnectionPool(host='m.dcinside.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /board/twice/8072990?recommend=1&page=14 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fdf41d69a20>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out',)) at: http://m.dcinside.com/board/twice/8072990?recommend=1&page=14
```

My AWS EC2 settings are like this:

EC2[here is python container.] has public DNS, IP and port :8080 is open.

Actually, python container is also django container and it works well.

Why this problem happened? and How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you able to `ping dcinside.com` from the EC2 instance? I actually tried and cannot reach that website.

Comment: @gkivanov I will try it after 1 hours later i cant do that now wait for me sorry

Comment: @gkivanov I did pings but as you said, it doesn't work. What do you think about it? I need your help..

Comment: Can you ping it from your local dev machine?

Comment: @gkivanov I pinged it at local linux, and local window. It seems that both are not works. But at local linux and local window, the code `req = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=False, headers=headers)` works well. Only problem is happen at ec2 instance. My ec2 instance is on oregon.

Comment: @gkivanov I tried this even on EC2 instance at the same region of my real country. But It does not work again.